# urdf_to_collada disrupts the robot model

Tags: ros, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

I am interesting in creating a single Collada model out of my robot URDF. I probably doing some thing  wrong her a simple example :
my rob.URDF file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_rob">
  <link name="base_cylinder">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="1" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 .8 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
         <cylinder length="1" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision> 
  </link>

  <link name="head_box">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.4 0.4 0.4"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.3 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="my_box_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_cylinder"/>
    <child link="head_box"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.7"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

in the RVIZ my model seems OK :
[image: image description]

but after i execute :

```
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada rob.URDF rob.dae
```

my rob.dae file looks like this in MeshLab :

[image: image description]

What am i doing wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197855/urdf_to_collada-disrupts-the-robot-model/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My experience has been that `urdf_to_collada` has difficulties with primitives such as boxes and cylinders in the past. I'd thus recommend generating simple meshes for your geometries and then retrying the conversion.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2014-11-30**:
I tried to use STL meshes, as you suggested, but unfortunately it does not helps.
Maybe you can direct me to a working example ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-11-30**:
I previously succesfully converted the atlas_v3 (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/55bddb26dda1672eac2bc134f2f06b9327e26ad0/atlas_description/robots/atlas_v3.urdf.xacro?at=default) model to the OpenRAVE COLLADA format, which is pretty complex (>20 links and joints etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect, when we use meshlab, it does not understand "joint" information so they display everything without understanding kinematics, please try urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=hoge.dae, this may display what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1